# iOS 7.0 User interaction disabled for controls inside UITableView backgroundView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I had custom view set as background view to UITableview.Which is utilise to perform some actions when tableview is blank.
I had some buttons on view & a action is associated with each button 
For iOS < 7 , action are called properly on buttons inside background view
But for iOS > 7 , actions set on buttons in backgroundView arent getting called.This seems interaction is disabled on backgroundView 
Is this an issue with iOS 7.Anyone else face same issue?[image: UITableview custom background view]

Comment: I think, this is a 'known issue', see the radar for that here: http://openradar.appspot.com/14707569

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `UITableViewWrapperView` view sitting in front of the background view intercepting interactions. Can you not just use the table's `tableHeaderView` property instead?

Comment: Using the tableHeaderView prevents you using constraints against the bottom of the view to lay out the content, e.g. to vertically center in the empty table.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this is a bad approach to add touchable items to tableView background view.
Secondly I'm not sure my fix will work for your case.

Try to implement following methods in your BackgroundView class:

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UIView* hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView != nil)
    {
        [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    }
    return hitView;
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    CGRect rect = self.bounds;
    BOOL isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point);
    if(!isInside)
    {
        for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
        {
            isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, point);
            if(isInside)
                break;
        }
    }
    return isInside;
}
```

By overriding those methods you are making all subviews of backgroundView as well as backgroundView itself touch sensitive.

Cheers!

---

UPDATE:

Sorry, this will not work. BackgroundView is located behind view with cells itself, so it will not receive touch.

Answer (score 0):

As specified in my comment, this is a known issue in iOS7, see the radar (http://openradar.appspot.com/14707569).

But my solution or workaround to this was to implement a 'proxy' view on top of the table which offers a protocol to forward the hitTest to a Delegate who implements that protocol.

EventFixBackrgoundView.h

```
@protocol EventFixBackrgoundViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (UIView *)eventFixHitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
@end

@interface EventFixBackrgoundView:UIView
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <EventFixBackrgoundViewDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

EventFixBackrgoundView.m

```
#import "EventFixBackrgoundView.h"
@implementation EventFixBackrgoundView
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(eventFixHitTest:withEvent:)])
    {
        return [self.delegate eventFixHitTest:point withEvent:event];
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
@end
```